# Computer vision training procedures: SVM/AdaBoost vs Neural Networks

Tags: neural-networks, image-processing, computer-vision, svm

With SVM, adaboost or similar alogrithms, image training sets must be cropped with specific constraints (keep image cropping ratio the same, have object tightly cropped, same resolution)

In general, does a training set for a neural network based classifier need to be generated under the same constraints?

If not, which constraints can be removed or loosened?